# What is the proper greeting for Yom HaShoah (Holocaust Day)?

Tags: minhag, social-convention, holocaust-shoah

Here in Israel, there are many customs surrounding Yom HaShoah; the morning siren, ceremonies, storytelling from survivors, etc. However, I'm not sure I've ever heard a way to greet someone that acknowledges this solemn day. Does anyone know or have any suggestions?

Comment: What is the proper greeting for Tish'ah BeAv?

Comment: @SethJ: Trick question, since we don't greet each other on Tishah B'Av.

Comment: @Aryeh Or is yours the trick question?

Comment: Only on Tishah B'Av do we forbid greetings. On minor fast days (which is probably the most similar in spirit and behavior as Yom HaShoah), many people in Israel say "Tzom Mo'il" or "Tzom Kal" to each other. I don't think it's a trick question. If I were to suggest a new greeting, it would be in the positive spirit of Tzom Mo'il, like "May this remembrance teach us."

Comment: Perhaps, although one might argue that the Holocaust of European Jewry was unprecedented in its horror, and rises, therefore, to a level akin to 9 Av, which represented a different sort of destruction.

Comment: BTW Many people do not acknowledge Yom HaShoah to be in Nissan, but rather put it as part of Tisha Be'Av. i.e. Yom HaShoah is a national day, not a religious one, so in that regard you can make up any greeting you like. i.e. this question may actually be more of a poll ("what do you do") rather than an answerable question.

Comment: Maybe hello??  ?

Answer (score 1):

Yom hashoa occurs during the month of Nissan. The custom around Nissan is to increase in Joy. While the holocaust is a serious and solemn time to remember it would be inappropriate during the month of nissan to alter our behavior to remember an event that invokes feelings of mourning thus the proper greeting would be the same as any other normal weekday or shabbos depending on what day it falls on.

Comment: actually I think that was a mistake. I don't have the sefarim to look it up but it was actually the chasam sofer not the shulchan aruch

Comment: What about our Sefira mourning?

Comment: good question. sefira changes very specific things but not our greetings. Also even though we limit specific things due to the mourning from sefira we also still don't say tachanun as the month of nissan is still joyous.

Comment: May be helpful to mention: Yom Hashoah _as such_ was not established by Jewish (religious) law. It was established by a resolution by Israel's parliament in 1951 and by a law in 1955, amended 1959. I'd illustrate that preceding and parallel religious decisions can sympathize with Yom HaShoah: After the State of Israel was founded (1948), the Chief Rabbinate held a "perpetual" (תמידי) remembrance day for Diaspora martyrs on 10 Tevet, particularly Jan 11, 1949; Dec 19, 1949; Dec 30, 1950. The date 10 Tevet is the long established fast for the start of Nebuchadnezzar's siege of Jerusalem.